# SparkSQL error: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have installed Spark in windows machine(**standalone**) and trying to connect HDP 2.6 hive metastore which is available in VM using Spark app.

I have used **NAT** as Network Adapter for **HDP 2.6** VM.
While I am trying to connect hive metastore (**HDP 2.6 VM**) from **Spark application** (***Local mode on Windows machine***),  I am getting below error message.

```
17/08/12 17:00:16 INFO metastore: Waiting 1 seconds before next connection attempt.
17/08/12 17:00:17 INFO metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://172.0.0.1:9083
17/08/12 17:00:38 WARN metastore: Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...
17/08/12 17:00:38 INFO metastore: Waiting 1 seconds before next connection attempt.
17/08/12 17:00:39 WARN Hive: Failed to access metastore. This class should not accessed in runtime.
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllDatabases(Hive.java:1236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<clinit>(Hive.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:503)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:191)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:266)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client$lzycompute(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply$mcZ$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.externalCatalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog$lzycompute(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder.build(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$instantiateSessionState(SparkSession.scala:1050)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:130)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:623)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:691)
    at com.psl.spark.RemoteHiveConnSpark1_6$.main(RemoteHiveConnSpark1_6.scala:29)
    at com.psl.spark.RemoteHiveConnSpark1_6.main(RemoteHiveConnSpark1_6.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1523)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:86)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:132)
```

**Spark application:**

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

/**
 * @author prasanta_sahoo
 */
object RemoteHiveConnSpark1_6 {

  def main(arg: Array[String]) {

    //Create conf object
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("RemoteHiveConnSpark1_6")
      .setMaster("local") // local mode
      .set("spark.storage.memoryFraction", "1")
      System.setProperty("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://172.0.0.1:9083");

    //create spark context object
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
    //hiveContext.setConf("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://172.0.0.1:9083");

    //disable case sensitivity of SQL
    //hiveContext.sql("set spark.sql.caseSensitive=false");
    hiveContext.sql("FROM default.sample_07 SELECT code, description, total_emp, salary").collect().foreach(println)
  }

}
```

**Can anyone please help me to solve the issue?**

Answer (score -1):

To connect with Hive metastore, following configurations are required,

spark.yarn.dist.files  ///apps/spark/hive-site.xml,///apps/spark/datanucleus-rdbms-4.1.7.jar,///apps/spark/datanucleus-core-4.1.6.jar,///apps/spark/datanucleus-api-jdo-4.2.1.jar

spark.sql.hive.metastore.version

Please confirm those configuration are there.